# Using a variable for the app name {% url %} in Django template

Tags: django

In my template, I want to refer to a certain URL, let's say it's named `homepage`. However, this named URL is available in two of my apps, and I am using the same html page that needs to sometimes refer to the one app, and sometimes to the other app. I now have this:

```
<a href="{% if app_name == 'app1' %}{% url 'app1:homepage' %}{% else %}{% url 'app2:homepage' %}{% endif %}">link</a>
```

This is not great and doesn't scale well (sometimes there could be up to 4 apps that may be used here). Ideally I'd use something like this:

```
<a href="{% url app_name + ':homepage' %}">link</a>
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a way to somehow using the `app_name` as a variable in the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
{% with dynamic_app_url=app_name|add:":"|add:"homepage" %}
    <a href="{% url dynamic_app_url %}">link</a>
{% endwith %}
```